# Leet Code problem #26 not sure why it’s not passing

Tags: javascript

Why is this not working I don’t see how there is a difference in the output.

My code:

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    //let newArr
    let newArr = [];
    let ht = {};
    
    for(let i=0; i< nums.length; i++){
        //create a ht index
        if(ht[nums[i]] === undefined){
            ht[nums[i]] = 1
        }
    }
    
    for(t in ht){
        let newT = parseInt(t)
        newArr.push(newT)
    }
    
    console.log(newArr)
    
    return newArr
};

removeDuplicates([1,1,4,4,6,7,8,9,9])
```

Comment: Please assume that we don't know what "Leet Code problem #26" is and explain what your code is supposed to do, and how it is failing.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/ Seems you need to return the length of the array and change the array to the shorter one

Answer (score 0):

You've to take advantage of the fact that array is sorted. When it is sorted, you can track first element to the last repeated same element and shift two pointers accordingly and return the index.
If you need the solution here is the one : (I originally submitted in Java and modified for the Javascript)

**Your code simply fails for input [1,1,2]**, examine yourself why and try to come up with your own solution or take the reference from the code below.

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    let capacity = nums.length;
    let firstIndex = 0;
    let lastIndex  = capacity -1;
    
    let index = 0;
    
    while(lastIndex >= firstIndex) {
       
        if(nums[lastIndex] == nums[firstIndex]) {   
            nums[index] = nums[firstIndex];
            firstIndex = lastIndex + 1;
            lastIndex =  capacity -1;
            index ++;
        }
        else {
            lastIndex--;
        }
    }
    return index;
  };
```